# Windows DNS Redirect to External Domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, internal-dns

Through Windows Server 2012 DNS I want to be able to let

http://wiki

resolve to our externally hosted company wiki site (e.g. wiki.example.com).

I know if it was internally hosted all I would need to do is to set up and A record but as it is outside of the network this doesn't work. Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

If your internal domain is example.com, there is no problem having an A record point to an address that is outside the internal network.

Apologies if I misunderstood the question; I don't have enough rep to comment!

Tim

Comment: That is the right answer. However, you might have to configure the webserver to serve the wiki for the virtual host `wiki`, if it's not the default website.

Answer (score -1):

You need URL redirection and DNS does only host resolution.

I can suggest to configure the web site (http://wiki) by IIS (on WinSrv 2012 DNS) and perform http redirection (to http://wiki.example.com) in the home page.